How do I resolve the CXSYNC_PORT wait lock?
I just got a new laptop (32GB RAM with Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 155H, 3.80 GHz) and installed SQL Server 2022 Dev edition. I'm running our application (Asp.Net) database on it for development.
Almost always when the application starts for the first time, a specific query gets stuck indefinitely. This query is quite simple, used to populate a checkbox list filter and should not cause any waits. It gets only those "Entities" that exist in a view called WOLight.
Select EntID, EntName from Entity (NoLock) Where Active=1 And Exists (Select 1 From WOLight (NoLock) Where TransID=Entity.EntID) Order by EntName

When I check the wait locks, I find the lock CXSYNC_PORT on this query. The only way to stop this is to restart SQL server. And then it works fine for some time. I read that this may happen due to insufficient threads on the sort operation, but couldn't find a solution.
Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryPufuNn0
The WOLight View:
CREATE View [dbo].[WOLIGHT] As
SELECT WORKORDER.WORKORDERID,
WORKORDER.OPID,
WORKORDER.AGENTID,
WORKORDER.TRANSID,
WORKORDER.CREATED,
WORKORDER.CREATEDON,
WORKORDER.UPDATED,
WORKORDER.DEPOT,
WORKORDER.RESP,
RS.FULLNAME RESPFULL,
WORKORDER.CONTNUM,
WORKORDER.WEIGHT,
WORKORDER.SEALNUM,
WORKORDER.OWNCONT,
WORKORDER.COMMODITY,
WORKORDER.REMARKS,
WORKORDER.PROCESSED,
WORKORDER.CLAGENTID,
WORKORDER.RETTRANSID,
WORKORDER.ESTLOCK,
WORKORDER.STATUSCHANGED,
WORKORDER.CUSTREMARKS,
WORKORDER.LASTEVENTID,
WORKORDER.LOADID,
WORKORDER.LAT,
WORKORDER.LNG,
WORKORDER.POSUPDATE,
WORKORDER.PRIORITY,
WORKORDER.WOSTATUS,
WORKORDER.STARTDEPOT,
(IsNull(STUFF((SELECT '; '+ GPar.GeoName + ' - ' + Geo.GeoName FROM WOGeoDest Join Geo On Geo.GEOID=WoGeoDest.GEOID  Join Geo GPar on Geo.Parent=GPar.GeoID Where WoGeoDest.WOID=WorkOrder.WORKORDERID Order By WoGeoDest.SERIAL,WoGeoDest.WOGeoID For XML Path('')),1,2,''),'')) as DEPOTLIST, 
WORKORDER.ORGCNTRY,
WORKORDER.DESTCNTRY,
WORKORDER.BOOKNUM,
WORKORDER.TYPECODE,
WORKORDER.BOLID,
WORKORDER.CONTLENGTH,
WORKORDER.CUSEVENTID,
WORKORDER.VOLUME,
WORKORDER.STATUSDATE,
WORKORDER.LOCREF,
WORKORDER.WHID,
WORKORDER.CLOSEDON,
WORKORDER.CLBY,
WORKORDER.WHOUT,
WORKORDER.PARENTWO,
IIF(AreaID Is Null, (Select AreaCode+'-'+Position From YPos Join Area On Area.AreaID=YPos.AreaID Where YPos.WOID=WorkOrder.WorkOrderID), (Select AreaName From Area Where Area.AreaID=WorkOrder.AreaID)) YardPos,
BOLMAIN.BOLNUM,BOLMAIN.WFSERIAL,BOLMAIN.CONTCUSID,
BOLMAIN.SHIPPERID,
BOLMAIN.RECEIVERID,
BOLMAIN.CARGOTYPE,CR.FULLNAME CREATEDBY, CL.FULLNAME CLBYNAME, CORRIDOR.CORID,CORCODE,BOLMain.BOLTYPE,BLREMARKS,BOLMain.INCO,
  CORRIDOR.CORNAME,CORTYPE,CUS.ENTNAME CONTCUSNAME,OP.ENTNAME OPNAME,NODOCDEL,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CALC AS ACTCALC WHERE WORKORDERID = WORKORDER.WORKORDERID AND ALERT = 1) AS ActiveAlerts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CALC AS ACKCALC WHERE WORKORDERID = WORKORDER.WORKORDERID AND ALERT = 2) AS AckAlerts,
(SELECT COUNT(WORKORDERID) FROM WORKORDER AS WOBOL WHERE WOBOL.BOLID = WORKORDER.BOLID) AS BOLCONTCOUNT, BOLTYPENAME,
LASTEVENT.DATATYPENAME + ' ' + LASTEVENT.INFO AS LASTEVENT,
(Case When WORKORDER.CREATEDON >= IsNull(LastEvent.EVENTDATE,WORKORDER.CREATEDON) Then WORKORDER.CREATEDON Else LastEvent.EVENTDATE End) As LASTEVENTDATE,
CUSEVENT.DATATYPENAME + ' ' + CUSEVENT.INFO AS CUSEVENT, CUSEVENT.EVENTDATE as CUSEVENTDATE,
CORRIDOR.WGID WFGID,
(IsNull(STUFF((SELECT '; '+ ServiceName FROM CorService CS Join WOService On CS.ServiceID=WOService.ServiceID Where WOService.WorkOrderID=WorkOrder.WORKORDERID Order By IsMain Desc, ServiceName For XML Path('')),1,2,''),'')) as ServiceList
From WORKORDER With (NoLock) Join BOLMain With (NoLock) On WORKORDER.BOLID=BOLMain.BOLID
Join USERS CR With (NoLock) On WORKORDER.CREATED=CR.USERID
Join CORRIDOR With (NoLock) On BOLMAIN.CORID=CORRIDOR.CORID
Left Join USERS CL On WORKORDER.CLBY=CL.USERID
Left Join USERS RS On WORKORDER.RESP=RS.USERID
Left Join ENTITY CUS On BOLMAIN.CONTCUSID=CUS.ENTID
Left Join DATAFULL AS LASTEVENT With (NoLock) ON LASTEVENT.DATAID = WORKORDER.LASTEVENTID
Left Join DATAFULL AS CUSEVENT With (NoLock) ON CUSEVENT.DATAID = WORKORDER.CUSEVENTID
Left Join BOLTYPE On BOLMAIN.BOLTYPE=BOLTYPE.BOLTYPE
Left Join ENTITY OP With (NoLock) On WORKORDER.OPID=OP.ENTID;

Any ideas?

Are you on newest CU for SQL Server? Which Windows version you have installed? Are there any noteworthy messages in SQL Server logs or Windows Event Viewer (Including system startup)? The CPU you have has P- and E-cores. Wouldn't surpise me either Windows or SQL Server having problems with these.

Yes. Latest updates. Windows 11 Home 23H2.  Nothing out of the ordinary in logs.

There could be several things going on under the hood here which may warrant an investigation - the view, indexes, execution plan, parallelism etc. However, can you try running this query with a serial plan - option (maxdop 1) - to understand whether serial plan is quicker and more efficient than the current parallel plan for this query?
Note - I am not suggesting to bring down the server maxdop, rather suggesting to find out if a serial plan is better in this particular case.

Paste The Plan

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryPufuNn0

@navigator thanks, you should add that to your Post so other people see it. Also please add your index definitions for all tables involved in this query.

That plan doesn't look like it "gets stuck indefinitely".  And the object names don't align with the query, so add the view definition, because this may not be a "simple" query.

Based on the execution plan provided I would say the SQL Server is not parallelising the query efficently. The query runs on 12 threads and is almost whole parallel, yet CPU time is 1213 ms compared to 730 ms elapsed time. This is less than 2x speedup.
Consider that you run other things on your laptop like Visual Studio (Code), SSMS, web browser, message communicator at minimum. They all might end up figting with SQL Server for resouces.
I would reduce the max degree of parallelism to 4 or even 2 on the instance level and also set cost threshold of parallelism to 50 or so. right now the respecive values seem to be 12 and 5(the default value). Also consider constraining SQL Server memory usage to fraction of available RAM. This way you should limit the impact SQL Sever has on everything else.
Other things to consider:

Put SQL Server on completely separate VM. That way it won't be interfering and won't be interfered by anything else
remove ORDER BY from the query and sort in the aplication.
check for intra-query deadlocks


Thank you for the explaining. I'm not a DB expert, but I will investigate changing these settings.

So, I've seen this reported related to Azure SQL (Managed Instance in my case) back to 2020.  Fall of 2024 as I write. We get this intermittently on queries that have always run quick....then executions that timeout (we have query timeout 30sec). People say don't set MAXDOP 1.  I understand the tech philosophy to this and people love to wax eloquent about how it subverts the Engine...high and mighty.   So I agree, setting MAXDOP on the Database Level or at an umbrella level isn't a good idea. BUT, I see this as an Azure Infrastructure/Resource bug, I'm guessing to do with threads. And not having another workaround, I have hinted specific queries with MAXDOP 1 to stop the madness and satisfy in the short run our paying customers
sp_query_store_set_hints @query_id = , @query_hints = N'OPTION (MAXDOP 1)'
So dump on me if you want but there is some weird science going on in the Az MI infrastructure and its the only workaround I have.
